# initialize object in nesterd class

Tags: c++

Through the use of the following 2 classes.
How do I go about creating customer queue objects and initialize their values using the customer constructor in the main function.

If fore say i'd like to have different types of customer,do I have 4 customer queue objects or is there a better way to go around?since there's the customer type variable in the class itself

Eg. CustomerQueue male;

ct = other, customer ( "tom",15)

```
class Customer
{
    public:

    // One for other
    Customer (char[MAX] name,int age);
    // copy constructor
    Customer (const Customer& );
    // To print out the customer
    void displayCust ();
    // Some other useful functions

    private:

    char *name;
    int age;
    char sex;
};


enum CustomerType {Senior, Lady, Other};

class CustomerQueue
{
    public:
    CustomerQueue ();
    ~CustomerQueue ();
    CustomerQueue (const CustomerQueue&);
    void enqueue (Customer );
    Customer dequeue ();
     // four isEmpty functions
    bool isGenEmpty () const;
     // four printQueue functions
    void displayQueue();
     // some other useful functions

    int getNo ();

    private:
    struct Node;
    typedef Node* NodePtr;
    struct Node
    {
         CustomerType ct;
         Customer cust;
         NodePtr next;
    };

    NodePtr head,tail;


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not hard.

```
int main()
{
    CustomerQueue q;
    q.enqueue(Customer("rita", 16));
    q.enqueue(Customer("sue", 16));
    q.enqueue(Customer("bob", 35));
}
```

As to your second question, you decide. Only you know the problem you are trying to solve, think about the problem not about the programming. In the problem does it make sense to have four queues? Make the program reflect the problem.